# Bluemix APIConnect Publishing a loopback project from command line

Tags: authentication, ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I am following the APIC tutorial documented here:

[Publishing a project from the command line](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/tutorial_cli_project_stage_command.html?cp=SSMNED_5.0.0%2F1-2-0-1-4)

I have gone through the steps in the tutorial to get into the APIConnect dashboard in Bluemix and into the Sandbox catalog.

I get the baseURL under api management:

e.g. `https://api.us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com/FREDusibmcom-dev/sb`

Then I  use that to

```
apic config:set 
catalog=apic-catalog://api.us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com/orgs/FREDusibmcom-dev/catalogs/sb 
app=apic-app://api.us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com/orgs/FREDusibmcom-dev/apps/acme-bank-Fred
```

After this as per the instructions, I try to login using my Bluemix credentials

```
apic login --server api.us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com -u fred -p mypassword
```

This fails with:

```
ERROR Login to api.us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com failed, please verify the servername and credential
```

Am I doing something wrong in regards to the servername or credentials that I am using?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `server` argument in the login command, use `us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com` instead. I think the `api` portion is throwing things off.

Once successful there, I also recommend that you run `apic edit` and proceed to `Log in with Bluemix` there, as that will ensure that you're able to publish applications to Bluemix from the CLI or API Designer.

Comment: Thanks, using 'us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com' for the server argument did the trick.  The api portion was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you used your actual username/password, and not "fred/mypassword".

If so, then the problem may be with the Bluemix URL.  There's now a simpler way to get the app identifier and catalog identifier (and to make sure you have the right Bluemix base URL).  The catalog & app tiles now have a link icon that you can click to easiy copy the catalog/app identifers:

[Geting the catalog identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/up4NZ.png)

The Bluemix base URL will the part immediately following `apic-catalog://` in the catalog identifier.

We're in the process of updating the docs with this.